# How to prevent last visited page reload in angular7?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

1. i am using angular7 router
2. this application maintain the visited pages. no re-load the page again
3. if i close the page separately at that time destroy variables and others
4. sample images i attached

for example

- first time i viewed candidates grid
- then i click particular candidates mail
- then i click the candidates grid tab

  - the grid is reload again.

in this case support router-outlet(angular7) or any other options to solve the requirement ?

[image: i need to maintain the visited pages]

Comment: Explain bit more about your requirement, and some code what you have tried?

Comment: i am using router-outlet. in this case every time page reload and my Component constructor invoke again.
i need to prevent actions

Comment: @Pardeep Jain Can i follow this link ( https://medium.com/@gerasimov.pk/how-to-reuse-rendered-component-in-angular-2-3-with-routereusestrategy-64628e1ca3eb )?

Answer (score 2):

is your problem grid/component re-creation or data getting fetched again?

you can't and shouldn't keep the component in dom when you are going to a different view, however you can definitely avoid data reloading.

Consider using ngrx/store or a service to hold the data and not load it again when the grid is recreated.

Comment: ok can provide any document or links or samples. i will Consider ngrx/store or service

Comment: you can look at angular documentation or ngrx documentation e.g. https://ngrx.io/guide/store